# all_ops_resolver.h:4:10: fatal error: tensorflow/lite/micro/compatibility.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, arduino, tensorflow-lite

System information

```
Host OS Platform and Distribution : Windows 10
Tensorflow version : 2.1.0
Target platform : Arduino Nano 33
```

Header are missing in hello_world sketches of tensorflow lite examples. So fails to build the deployment.

Following contains the headers I used.

```
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/all_ops_resolver.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/examples/hello_world/model.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_error_reporter.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_interpreter.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/testing/micro_test.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/schema/schema_generated.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/version.h"
```

Comment: What's the branch you're using? Does it happen on master?

Comment: I solved the issue by last update